# How to add % to total sum but only in row and not actully upgrade total price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // The percentage
    $percent = 15; // 15%
    // The cart total
    $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total; 

    // The conditional Calculation
    $fee = $cart_total >= 25 ? $cart_total * $percent / 100 : 0;

    if ( $fee != 0 ) 
        $cart->add_fee( __( "Extra", "woocommerce" ), $fee, false );
}
```

I'm looking for a code like this:

- Add % to total cart, but I **dont actully want it to update total cart price**
- I just want it to add extra row like it does now with "extra"

---

Example: you shop for 10 dollars

Total sum: 10 dollars
Extra: 11,5 dollars

I still want total sum to be 10 dollars, but just to show them if they pay 15% "extra" I will send something extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because this is shown 2x, use
>
> - `woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total` - checkout page
> - `woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total` - cart page

```php
function my_custom_fee_based_on_cart_total() {
    // optional
    //if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // The percentage
    $percent = 15; // 15%
    
    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    
    // The conditional Calculation
    $fee = $cart_total >= 25 ? $cart_total * $percent / 100 : 0;
    
    echo '<tr class="my-class"><th>Extra</th><td>' . wc_price($fee) . '</td></tr>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'my_custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'my_custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 0 );
```